# Custom Forms Styling

Tags: orchardcms

New to orchard. I'm trying to style a custom form without success. I've also been using the shape modeler.
I created a New ContentType and add Fields f1, f2, f3... I create a CustomForm. Now I want to wrap different divs around certain fields say

```
<div class="g1">
f1
f2
</div>
<div class="g2">
f4
f6
</div>
```

BTW I've tried this construct without success:

```
        dynamic content = @Model.Content;
    <div class="g1">
        if(@content.ContentTypeName.f1 || @content.ContentTypeName.f2)
        { @Dispaly(...)
        }
    </div>
```

Can this be done in the content.edit.cshtml view? 
If so please provide an example. 
Thanks

Also, is there any way to reflect the properties of Model.Content during runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally came up with a solution, albeit quite ugly, but it works:
In my alternate associated with the Content_Edit:

```
@{
    dynamic content = Model.Content;
 }

<div class="g1">
@{
     foreach (var item in content)
     {
         if (item.Model.GetType().Name == "BooleanField")
         {
             if (f.Name == "f1" || f.Name == "f2")
             {
                 @Display(item);
             }
          }
      }
 }
</div>
<div class="g2">        
@{
     foreach (var item in content)
     {
         if (item.Model.GetType().Name == "BooleanField")
         {
             if (f.Name == "f4" || f.Name == "f6")
             {
                 @Display(item);
             }
         }
     }
 }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What I did was create local zones in the Content_Edit alternate then rearrange the fields using placement.info

Placement.info:

```
<Match ContentType="MyForm">
    <Place Fields_Input_Edit-FirstField="MyFirstZone:1"/>
    <Place Fields_Input_Edit-SecondField="MySecondZone:1"/>
</Match>
```

Content.Edit-MyForm.cshtml:

```
<div class="edit-item">
    <div class="edit-item-primary">
        @if (Model.Content != null) 
        {
            <div class="edit-item-content">
                <div class="first-zone">
                    @Display(Model.MyFirstZone)
                </div>
                <div class="second-zone">
                    @Display(Model.MySecondZone)
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

Comment: This is a brilliantly simple approach the provides great flexibility in laying out custom forms. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Typically in Orchard, you override templates for parts and fields, not for the whole content item. Shape tracing can help you determine what template alternates you can use for each field and even generate the file with the default code for you to modify.

Also, Model.Content, if anything, will be a zone, not the content item. Depending on which template you're in, you may be able to use Model.ContentItem instead.

Comment: Hi Bertrand- Seems we're going round in circles on this question... Question- can you wrap divs around specific fields through .cshtml? If so please provide and an example. Thanks Tony

Comment: That sounds a little rude. I don't see a circle here. Override the template for a specific field, and you can give it any markup you want, including surrounding it with a div. http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Accessing-and-rendering-shapes

Comment: @tonyb206 An example probably isn't necessary.  Just click the button in the shape tracing tool to add an alternate.  You can read more about alternates in the documentation.

Comment: Sorry Bertrand, not trying to be rude, just frustrated- Been screwing with this for a week...
I realize one can create an alternate at each field level. But it's the level above this-the Content_Edit Level I'm interested in:
This seams like the only place I can accomplish the "specific" div wrapping as shown in my original question above-- Thanks

Comment: But you said you wanted to wrap a div around certain fields. So why can't you create an alternate template for that field and put that div in there? There is also the concept of a wrapper in Orchard, but you don't even need that here. Oh, I see, you wanted to wrap several fields inside of a single div? That wasn't clear from your question. Then your ugly hack may be the easiest way to get that result.